# How to get an IPhone or IPad (iOS 5.x) to properly recognize my certificate root authority

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl, certificate, self-signed

I created a self-signed root authority certificate using `makecert`. I created an SSL certificate issues by that authority and bound my IIS 7 website with it. I then pushed the root certificate to my iPad using IPhoneConfigurationUtility. However when I browse to my HTTPS site with my iPad, it still doesn't trust it. What am I doing wrong? What information can I provide here to help you guys help me out.

I followed the steps on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733813.aspx) to do this. The only exception is that I'm on IIS 7

Comment: Same problem on iOS 4.3.5 and 5.1.1.

Comment: I can create a profile in the iPhone Configuration Utility, and push the profile to the device containing my certificate. The device says my profile is trusted, but I still get certification warnings when going to my sites that are signed with it.

Answer (score 1):

What version of iOS do you have?

Apparently ,there were [some issues](http://ios.web.cern.ch/content/how-install-personal-certificate-iphone) with SSL handling on iOS 5. Try to install it over the air (instead of through iPhone configuration utility)